# How to determine pythagorean triples that have a slope closest to 1

Tags: prime-numbers, pythagorean-triples

I'm not a mathematician, and I'm not sure how to phrase this question properly, so please bear with me as I stumble through the question.

Considering Pythagorean's Theorem a²+b²=c²

I'm looking for solutions that fit the following requirements:

1. two of the prime leg, even leg or hypotenuse must be prime numbers
2. the third number must be an integer
3. the slope is close to 1

The third requirement is obviously not clear. Here are some examples:

```
prime leg   even leg   hypotenuse   slope
---------   --------    ---------   -----
      3          4            5     0.750
      5         12           13     0.417
     11         60           61     0.183
     19        180          181     0.106
     29        420          421     0.069
     59       1740         1741     0.034
     61       1860         1861     0.033
```

But as you see in the table, the larger numbers become less and less steep.

How would you go about calculating this?

Comment: The slope is the ratio between the legs, right? Which is to say, the $\tan$ of any of the acute angle in your triangle.

Comment: Broad suggestion: try looking through [formulas for generating Pythagorean triples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formulas_for_generating_Pythagorean_triples) and try to identify ones which produce the properties you want and increasing slopes, or have a subsequence which does.

Comment: [I have answered a similar question here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2409907/how-can-you-find-a-pythagorean-triple-with-a2b2-c2-and-a-b-close-to-5-7/2409929#2409929) . Might be helpful.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is your motivation for finding such triples?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are going to have a hard time with this. Clearly, your Pythagorean triples are primitive. Which means that there are natural numbers $u,v$ such that your so-called prime leg is equal to $u^2-v^2$, the even leg is equal to $2uv$ and the hypotenuse is equal to $u^2+v^2$.

The fact that your prime leg is equal to $u^2-v^2=(u-v)(u+v)$, and at the same time a prime number means that we must have $u-v=1$. Rewriting the above expressions for the three sides using this gives a prime leg of length $2v+1$ and even leg of length $2(v^2+v)$. The ratio between these two sides is just going to get further and further away from $1$ as you pick bigger and bigger primes for your prime side.

As a side note, the length of the hypotenuse will always be $(v+1)^2+v^2=2(v^2+v)+1$, which is $1$ more than the length of the even leg. You probably already spotted this pattern from your table.

Comment: I haven't touched the "hypotenuse is prime" condition. Taking that into account will just rule out a bunch of the triangles you get from this procedure, so it doesn't really affect the result.

Comment: To clarify, "you are going to have a hard time with this" is an understatement for "this is impossible".

Comment: @MichaelLugo That depends entirely on what the OP defines as "success". It has been vague, so I'll be vague.

Answer (score 0):

I can't help much with the prime numbers but I can help with getting close to a slope of $1$ in Pythagorean triples. We want to find triples where $|A-B|=1$ and, to do that, we solve $A^2+(A\pm1)^2=C^2$ for $n$. (I'll spare you the details.) These numbers get rarer and rarer so most can only be found programmatically.

$$\text{We let }(n=\sqrt{2m^2\pm1}-m)\text{ and select }m,n\text{ whenever n is an integer and }n<m.\text{ We use }\pm\text{in our test because sometimes }A>B\text{ and sometimes }A<B.$$ Then we can generate the following triples as $f(m,n)$ using Euclid's formula.
$$f(2,1)=(3,4,5)\quad 0.75$$
$$f(5,2)=(21,20,29)\quad 1.05$$
$$f(12,5)=(119,120,169)\quad 0.991666666666667$$
$$f(29,12)=(697,696,985)\quad 1.0014367816092$$
$$f(70,29)=(4059,4060,5741)\quad 0.999753694581281$$
$$f(169,70)=(23661,23660,33461)\quad 1.00004226542688$$
$$f(408,169)=(137903,137904,195025)\quad 0.999992748578721$$
$$f(985,408)=(803761,803760,1136689)\quad 1.00000124415248$$
$$f(2378,985)=(4684659,4684660,6625109)\quad 0.999999786537337$$
$$f(5741,2378)=(27304197,27304196,38613965)\quad 1.00000003662441$$
$$f(13860,5741)=(159140519,159140520,225058681)\quad 0.999999993716245$$
$$f(33461,13860)=(927538921,927538920,1311738121)\quad 1.00000000107812$$
$$f(80782,33461)=(5406093003,5406093004,7645370045)\quad 0.999999999815024$$
$$f(195025,80782)=(31509019101,31509019100,44560482149)\quad 1.00000000003174$$
$$f(470832,195025)=(183648021599,183648021600,259717522849)\quad 0.999999999994555$$
$$f(1136689,470832)=(1070379110497,1070379110496,1513744654945)\quad 1.00000000000093$$
$$f(2744210,1136689)=(6238626641379,6238626641380,8822750406821)\quad 0.99999999999984$$
$$f(6625109,2744210)=(36361380737781,36361380737780,51422757785981)\quad 1.00000000000003$$
$$f(15994428,6625109)=(211929657785303,211929657785304,299713796309065)\quad 0.999999999999995$$

Comment: Thank you for your efforts!