# Can $(2n-1)^2+2(2n-1)k$ generate primes for $n>1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I have a function $$A=(2n-1)^2+2(2n-1)k$$ that I have proven, to myself, to generate $all$ values of $A$ for Pythagorean triples where GCD(A,B,C) is an odd square – so it includes all primitives. Let's assume my proof is valid because this is not about generating triples. In this function, $n$ is the number of a set of triples where the difference between $B$ and $C$ is the $n^{th}$ odd square and $k$ is the number of the member triple in that set.

$Set_1$ ($n=1$) includes all odd numbers $>1$ so it includes all prime numbers except $2$. My problem is that I have not been able to find prime numbers among those generated when $n>1$. Can this function generate primes for $n\ge 2$ or there something about it that will not allow and f(n,k) to generate primes when $n>1?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$(2n-1)^2+2(2n-1)k$ is never a prime when $n>1$ (assuming $k\ge 0$) because
$$ (2n-1)^2+2(2n-1)k = (2n-1)(2n-1+2k) $$

Comment: Thanks. I never thought to expand, collect terms, and factor.

Comment: @poetasis: I didn't even do that -- just noticed that each of the terms in your expression is _explicitly_ a multiple of $2n-1$.

Comment: Thanks anyway. It helped me help a guy with [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3181424/how-to-determine-pythagorean-triples-that-have-a-slope-closest-to-1/3186670#3186670) where I failed miserably before.